# use VCL Styles get TStylemanager not found

Tags: delphi, vcl, vcl-styles

I migrate a very big VCL Application from Delphi 7 to XE and now to Seattle.
Now I want to use VCL Styles, I go in Project Options and enable one but I get always the compilation error that the ''TStyleManager'' class is not defined. 
But why?

Answer (score 1):

`TStyleManager` is defined in the `Vcl.Themes` unit, which you obviously must use in order to be able to refer to `TStyleManager`.

```
uses
  Vcl.Themes;
```

This information can be obtained from the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager

Comment: The problem is Vcl.Themes and Vcl.Styles are referenced in the file

Comment: My answer explains your compilation error. If you have a more detailed question about specific code, that would be a new question. Make sure you include a full [mcve] when you ask it.